# Spring Security 4 : Authentication failed: password does not match stored value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security in my application. User can correctly login to system, but after few logins and logouts it is no more possible to login again. I'm getting an error:

```
Authentication failed: password does not match stored value
```

I'm using java config like this:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/root-context.xml")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select email,password, enabled from users where email=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role from user_roles where email=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").permitAll();
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me, what could be a problem?

**EDIT**

I found out, that for some reason, the saved hash in DB is no more correct, if I replace it in DB with another one, I can again log in. What is causing it?

Comment: Have you changed anything lately to your configuration? The only sensible explanation I have is that you changed the `PasswordEncoder`. Or maybe you changed it only on one side: the authentication (the encoder is used to compare passwords) or the service / dao that persists the user in DB (the encoder should be used to encrypt the clear password)?